# How to change the color and alignment of a wrap text -css

Tags: css, sass

How do I change the color and alignment for a line of text that wraps ?. Basically, I have a div with some content and if the text wrap because of space issue. Then , I want the second line to be color green and right align.

I have create a simple fiddle.. Need the second line to be right align and color change.

**SCSS:**

```
.heading {
    font-size: 40px;
        &:first-line {
            color: red;
        }
 }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="heading">
    this is a test for wraping text in multiple line. testing
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6rLno8ht/9/)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This:**

```css
.heading{
  font-size: 40px;
  color:green;
  text-align-last:right;
}

.heading:first-line{
  color:initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
   this is a test for wraping text in multiple line. testing
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Css selectors only allow for the first line to be selected. However, there is a library called lining.js that allows for the result you are after. Below is the code snippet which should resolve your issue.

HTML:

```
<div class="heading" data-lining>
   this is a test for wraping text in multiple line. this is some additional text to show the wrapping effect.
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zmmbreeze/lining.js/7077712b/build/lining.min.js"></script>
```

SCSS:

```
.heading {
     font-size: 40px;
     .line:nth-of-type(2) {
         color:green;
         text-align:right;
       }
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6rLno8ht/95/

Hope this helps!